# Surjective when A is smaller than B

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia uses this picture for injective and surjective functions.

[image]

The top right is non-surjective. I have added a mapping on, is this now surjective? Why/why not?

Comment: This is not a well defined function...

Comment: Top-right is not even a map. A map is when $\forall x\in X, \exists! y\in Y$, which is not the case depicted.

Answer (score 3):

Some authors would call it a surjective relation. However, very few (but never too few) would call it a surjective *function* (or mapping) because the common definition of function would be that each element in the domain is related to exactly one element of the codomain.

Answer (score 3):

No, because it's not a function. A function can only map each number in the domain to exactly one element in the codomain. Since in the top right, you've drawn 3 to map to both C and A, it ceases to be a function.